# xls exported from iReport has corrupted cells

Tags: jasper-reports

I've got a problem with exporting report from Jespersoft iReport 5.6.0 to xls and xlsx format. In pdf everything is displayed properly but in xls and xlsx format values which are longer than cell width, are replaced by #########

I've experminted with these properties:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.width
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height
```

but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When You manually extend the column in the excel the ######### will be shown normally. I suggest make smaller font for given column, or in ireport design wider columns/fields.

Or you can use: net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row property for each field.

Comment: I know I could resize the column but in the long run I could receive even longer number and the problem will occure again. I'm rather looking for possibility to brake number instead of changing columns size.

Comment: Then use: net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row

Comment: Thank for your response but unfortunately it didn't work. There was no change at all.